# I get a consistency y error when I use my second hard drive

Tags: boot

I have two hard drives with win8 installed to both of them. Sometimes, when I boot from the second one (with F12 boot-menu and the second drive selection) and later reboot and start my PC from  the first one, I get a disk error for a consistency problem. Windows ask for a disk check and after that, I can't anymore boot from the second drive or have access to it. Why this happens and how can I prevent it? What options do I have except from reinstalling windows?
Thanks 
Stavros

Comment: I would start by replacing the hdds.  It sounds like the second hdd has some sector problems.

Comment: Check how you shutdown both systems. Is it a full shutdown or a "hybrid" shutdown (partial hybernation - new in Win8 - only OS state is hybernated). I think hybernation state is considered no longer valid after disk writes - maybe this is the reason for consistency problems later when booting drive.